# Encryption in or used by libgit2 and libgit2sharp? Export Control Classification Numbers?

Tags: libgit2, libgit2sharp

Do libgit2 and libgit2sharp have Export Control Classification Numbers (ECCN)?  If so, where can I find them?  (I didn't find them on github for either project.)

If not, does either contain encryption?  And, does either use encryption, including calling encryption in other programs (for example, using SSL to create secure connections)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please elaborate why you need an answer to this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If libgit2 contained encryption code, it would fall under section 740.13(e) of the [EAR](http://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/regulations/export-administration-regulations-ear), which means it doesn't need an ECCN.

However, libgit2 doesn't itself do encryption. It relies on openssl and libssh to do this, but as open-source projects, they don't require ECCN's either.

For more on this topic, see the [most official answer about Mozilla code you're likely to ever get](http://hecker.org/mozilla/eccn).

Also, I'm a software engineer, not a lawyer. Take this advice at your own risk.

Comment: It does have a SHA-1 implementation in `src/hash/hash_generic.c` as a fall-back in case it doesn't link against OpenSSL (but those cases would be rare).